# Close material-ui dialog by onClick on an image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, material-ui

I'm trying to add a clickable  image to close a material-ui dialog.
The props.onRequestClose works properly when I click outside the dialog but the onClick doesn't response.

What am I missing?

```
const ChangePasswordDialog = (props) =>  (
        <Dialog open={props.open} onRequestClose={props.onRequestClose} modal={false}>
            <div className="close-popup">
                <Svg onClick={props.onRequestClose} viewBox="0 0 22.75 22.75">{closePopup}
                </Svg >
            </div>
        </Dialog>
);

ChangePasswordDialog.propTypes = {
open:PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
onRequestClose:PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Comment: are you updating the `open` value in parent inside `props.onRequestClose` method ?

Comment: Yes I set the value of `open` to false. In addition, every time I click outside the dialog it closes it so `props.onRequestClose` should work.

Comment: What kind of component is Svg? Is the onClick even fired when you click the svg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding a prop called onClick to the Svg components.
Here is the code for the Svg components if someone needs:

```
class Svg extends Component{
render() {
    const {children, viewBox, onClick} = this.props;
    return(
        <div onClick={onClick}>
            <SvgIcon viewBox={viewBox}>
                {children}
            </SvgIcon>
        </div>
       )
    };
  }

Svg.propTypes = {
   children:PropTypes.any.isRequired,
   viewBox:PropTypes.string,
   onClick:PropTypes.function
 };

export default Svg;
```